# Google API batch request with axios

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to create an axios request for batch endpoint of google API, but the documentation is quite confusing to me and i don't understand how to structure my request properly.

As a simple example, I would like to request files using drive API and files endpoint.

so the batch url would be: 
https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3

and the batched requests would have url of: 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

Based on my understanding the request would look like:

```
axios.post({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed;"
    }
    body: [
        {
            <fieldname>: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files,
            method: "GET",
            bearer: `Authorization: Bearer <my bearer token>`
        },
        {
            <fieldname>: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files,
            method: "GET",
            bearer: `Authorization: Bearer <my bearer token>`
        }

    ]
})
```

My biggest concern is what name should the URL field in the body have?
Or am I creating the request object in a wrong way?

Comment: At Drive API, you can create the request body of batch request from this official document. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch If this information was not useful for you, I apologize.

Comment: Were you able to pull this off?